# How to find the subsequence of number in java in simplest way

Tags: java

I am using below program for printing all possible sub sequence

```
class Test {

    static void printSubSeqRec(String str, int n, int index, String curr) {
        if (index == n) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(curr);

        for (int i = index + 1; i < n; i++) {
            curr += str.charAt(i);
            printSubSeqRec(str, n, i, curr);

            curr = curr.substring(0, curr.length() - 1);
        }
    }

    static void printSubSeq(String str) {
        int index = -1;
        String curr = "";

        printSubSeqRec(str, str.length(), index, curr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "24";
        printSubSeq(str);
    }

}
```

Output:

2
4
24

Is there any other way for getting the same result?

Comment: Can you store them in an array or table? Then you should be able to check if the subsequence already exists before going in the recursive function

Answer (score 2):

In solving this I figured I wanted to generate the following pairs of indices in the given order. The first element is the start of the substring and the second is the limit for a four character string.

```
      [0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [0,2], [1,3], [2,4], [0,3], [1,4], [0,4]
```

This is the simplest way I could come up with.

```java
      String numb = "1234";
      for (int z = 1; z <= numb.length(); z++) {
         for (int k = z; k <= numb.length(); k++) {
            System.out.println(numb.substring(k - z, k));
         }
      }
```

If you want to do it recursively, here is one way.

```
  String numb = "1234";
  subseq(numb, 0, 1, 1);

  public static void subseq(String v, int z, int k, int i) {
      System.out.println(v.substring(z, k));
      if (k < v.length()) {
         subseq(v, z + 1, k + 1, i);
      }
      else if (z > 0) {
         subseq(v, 0, 1 + i, i + 1);
      }
   }
```

1. The first recursive call to `subseq` is such that `z` and `k` are incremented by 1 each.
2. The `i` serves as the next amount to increment `k`
3. So the second call to `subseq` calls with `z` back to 0 and `k` to `1+i`
   In that second call, `i` is also increased by 1
4. This continues until `k >= length of string` and `z = 0` which is the entire
   String and the last string printed.

But I prefer the nested loops solution.

Comment: Above code will work fine but if I want to generate for big range for example if  I need subsequesne for all number from range [1 to 1000cr] then it will take too much time.

Comment: When you say `1000cr` I presume you mean a `1000` character string.  I just did a test, storing them in a preallocated `List` of size  `(n(n+1))/2`.  It consistently takes less than `500 milliseconds`. It is printing them all out that takes a long time.  Can you edit your question and provide more information/examples of what you want.

Comment: This is for 1000cr.. but if we want to do this thing in a loop. for example for (int i = 1; i <= 1000cr; i++) { logic for finding subsequence for each number}  It will find subsequence from 1 to 1000cr number

Comment: for (long i = 0; i < Long.parseLong("100000000000"); i++) {
   String numb = String.valueOf(i);
   for (int z = 0; z <= numb.length(); z++) {
    for (int k = z; k <= numb.length(); k++) {
     // System.out.println(numb.substring(k - z, k));
    }
   }

  } That I wanted to say

Comment: Well, I don't believe I can improve this. Instead of `100,000,000,000` as you suggested I tried `1,000,000,000`. Just to compute the total number of subsequences (just the number) took `75` seconds. That number is `44,012,345,734`. It would be significantly larger if I used your example. And that didn't include the time to actually find the sequences. And then storing them would have memory problems and writing them to disk would take even more time.  I recommend you re-edit your original post and explain in detail what you want. Perhaps someone else can offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str= "243";
    for(int i = 1; i<= str.length();i++){
        int m = 0;
        for(int j =0;j < str.length() && m+i <= str.length();j++){
            System.out.println(str.substring(j,m+i));
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

result :

```
2 4 3 24 43 243
```

Comment: Above code will work fine but if I want to generate for big range for example if I need subsequesne for all number from range [1 to 1000cr] then it will take too much time

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer doing it without recursion:

```java
static void printSubSeq(String str) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= str.length() - i; j++) {
            int k = j + i - 1;
            for(int l = j; l <= k; l++) System.out.print(str.charAt(l));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```